# How to use GAP to check whether an element is a square element in $G$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap

Let $G$ be a finite group, $Z(G)$ be the center of $G$, if $|Z(G)|=2$, then how to use GAP to check whether $1\neq a\in Z(G)$ a suqare element in $G$? In particular how about $G=\Omega_8^+(3)$?

The following commands are what I know. Can someone give me some hints to this proplem. Thank you in advance!

G:=OmegaPlus(8,3);

A:=Centre(G);

L:=List(A);

L[2];

S:=SylowSubgroup(G,2);

Comment: Compute representatives of the conjugacy classes of $S$ and check whether any of those square to L[2].

Comment: Okay, Thank you very much!